# Can You run Node.js on a shared drive?

Tags: node.js

I am running Windows 10. I have a Seagate PersonalCloud on which I store all my web development code because I am not always on the same computer. I generally use S-Drive to access this code. I rarely have an issue running anything from it **except** when I need node.

Running the commands "npm install" and "npm install live-server -g" get the desired result messages. However, when I run "npm start", it starts the web server until I make a change in the code. (I have tried this with very simple html code only with the same results.)

Now, if I copy the file over to the local drive and follow the same steps, it all works fine.

Is there some special setting I might be missing? I used the basic install package for Windows.

Thanks in advance, 
Jen

**update** Here's the error message:

```
Serving "S:\PersonalCloud\jennylynneh\web development\learnkey\MTA HTML5 App Dev Fundamentals (Exam 98-375)\unraveling_html5_css_javascript\Chapter01\Exercise-01-01" at http://127.0.0.1:58680
Ready for changes
GET /favicon.ico 404 283.349 ms - 150
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 3221225477
npm ERR! unraveling-html5-2nd-edition@1.0.0 start: `live-server --port=0`
npm ERR! Exit status 3221225477
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the unraveling-html5-2nd-edition@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jlhar\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-11-27T20_03_21_298Z-debug.log /c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: line 34: 15668 Segmentation fault      "$NODE_EXE" "$NPM_CLI_JS" "$@"
```

Using `npm install live-server --only=dev` I get:

```
npm ERR! file S:\PersonalCloud\jennylynneh\web development\learnkey\MTA HTML5 App Dev Fundamentals (Exam 98-375)\unraveling_html5_css_javascript\Chapter02\Exercise-02-17\package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected token in JSON at position 299 while parsing near '...  "license": "ISC", [ % x   % X    ...'i
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
```

Comment: What exactly happens when you change the code?

Comment: It kicks out of the live-server and gives a ELIFECYCLE error

Comment: Perhaps you could add the log of the error to your question.

Comment: `npm install live-server -g` installs to your local drive. I'm not familiar with it but you could drive `npm install live-server --dev` so it is local to the project and then use `npm start` which should called the `live-server` command from within your project on `S:` rather than `C:`